# error while starting open ssh : /usr/sbin/sshd: /lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /usr/sbin/sshd)

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd, shared-library, yocto

I am working on an embedded board, to access that board I need ssh to work smoothly. Currently, for debugging purpose I am using serial connection to access the board.

Now, when I try to start openssh it throws following error:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd: /lib/libcrypt.so.1: version `XCRYPT_2.0' not found (required by /usr/sbin/sshd)
```

I have the correct libcrypt.so.1 which provides 'XCRYPT_2.0' in /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1

So this is what I did :
rm /lib/libcrypt.so.1

ln -s /usr/lib/libcrypt.so.1 /lib/libcrypt.so.1

I can get the ssh to work. However, I figured out that I need deleted /lib/libcrypt.so.1 - if this shared object is not present then I believe pam_unix.so / some other shared objects are giving me problem. Because I could not login to the board, even serially (for the next reboot).

I don't even see the 'login' prompt.

My question is, is there a way with which I can provide shared object path to sshd dynamically something like?

/etc/init.d/sshd < dynamically provide shared object path  > start

or

/usr/sbin/sshd < dynamically provide shared object path  > start

More info about the system:

Using openssh 7.8/7.8p1 version

Using Yocto Thud (2.6) to get the root file system.

Running Linux 4.14

Comment: same problem in debian testing exist...

Answer (score 1):

You can set the directories to search for shared libraries by using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` enviroment variable.

Copy your libcrypt.so.1 to e.g. /etc/ssh/libs/ (create the directory first of course), and start sshd thusly:

```
env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/etc/ssh/libs /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Ad the first path to the invocation, whatever parameters are passed to sshd still need to be passed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem
and it's due to a change in Yocto version
previous version was installing libcrypto.so.1 as part of glibc
now it's a package called libcrypto-....rpm
so when you remove the /lib/libcrypto* you force ssh to reuse the one under /usr/lib